# C# dataGridView no DataContext

Tags: c#, datagridview, datacontext

atm i am trying to write a code what will fill my DataGridView with data from MySQL

```
string sql2Params = "Database=" + database + ";Data Source=" + host + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + pass;
        string sql2Query = "SELECT * FROM `wagons` WHERE 1";

        //MySqlConnection sql2Connection = new MySqlConnection(sql2Params);
        //MySqlCommand sql2Command = new MySqlCommand(sql2Query, sql2Connection);

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(sql2Params))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql2Query, connection))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                da.Fill(dt);
                wagonDataGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I found this one, then checked in different web sites that its correct and trying to use in my own project, but i am getting error

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataContext' and no extension method 'DataContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What this can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DataSource isntead of DataContext, no property DataContext in winform datagrid